# How to include roles in another role

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I have organized all my playbooks into roles. Now that I have all the roles, I'm trying to create a new role that would include all the other roles.

In Ansible, is it possible to create a role that just calls other roles? If so, is it possible to do it as a list, like in a playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: webservers
  roles:
  - role1
  - role2
  - role3
```

Answer (score 6):

You can, for example, add them as dependencies in the `meta/main.yml`:

```yaml
dependencies:
  - role: role1
  - role: role2
  - role: role3
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-role-dependencies).

Alternatively you can use [`import_role`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_role_module.html) or [`include_role`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html) (example below for the include version).

```yaml
- include_role:
    name: 'role1'

# or with a loop
- include_role:
    name: "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - role1
    - role2
    - role3
```

The different options to use a role are all synthesized in the [role documentation - Using roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-roles)

But if I were you, I would not create a role that contains all other roles, but include them in a playbook. Adding them in a role doesn't give you any value.

Comment: Using dependencies makes installing the required roles much easier, as `ansible-galaxy` will pull them automatically for you when installing the parent role.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue by adding the following in `meta/main.yml`:

```yaml
---
dependencies:
  - role: role1
  - role: role2
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you read the last warning in @toydarian answer and limit role dependencies to the very strict minimum necessary. Practice will most probably show you that it is very hard to manage and maintain.